# Multiple Series on Bar with Negative Stack graph

Tags: graph, highcharts

How can I present multiple series on each side,. while using Bar Negative Stack?
I want (Dogs+Puppies) on one side while (Cats+Kittens) on other.

Here is the demo snippet. http://bpaste.net/show/sek3b8oOqRi5BjbRWiR3/

Comment: I don't understand the question.  You have multiple series on each side (3 series on negative, 1 on positive).  Are you looking to just disable the stacking?  http://jsfiddle.net/VWBnf/1/

Comment: Just reread your question, if you want Kittens with Cats just reverse the their sign: http://jsfiddle.net/VWBnf/2/